# Co-authors plus problems with query_post

Tags: query-posts

I had a query_post that worked, aimed lists only posts by author own, but now that I updated wordpress stopped working.

The query_post only works when you have only one author.

I updated WordPress 3.2.1. to 3.7.1

Index.php

```
<?php $post_count = 0; ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="page">
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php 
    if ($user_level == '1'){ 
        global $current_user;
        get_currentuserinfo();
        query_posts("author=$current_user->ID&showposts=4&paged=$paged"); 
    } 
?>
<div id="main">
        <ul id="navigationMenu">
            <li>
                <?php $walker = new Menu_With_Description; ?>
                <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'content-menu', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu', 'walker' =>  $walker ) ); ?>
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>
<div class="title-s">Posts</div>
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

            <div <?php post_class(); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                <p class="contador-comentario">
                <?php comments_popup_link( '0', '1', '%', 'comments-link', 'Comments are off for this post');?>
                </p>
                <div class="title-s">
                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php printf(__('Post: %s', 'kubrick'), the_title_attribute('echo=0')); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                </div>
                <div class="resume">
                <?php the_excerpt() ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php $post_count++; endwhile; ?>

<?php if ($post_count == '0' and $user_level == '1'){ 
        echo 'tour';
        echo $post_count;
        } ?>    

        <div id="nav-below" class="navigation">
            <div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link( __( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> Older posts', 'twentyten' ) ); ?></div>
            <div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Newer posts <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentyten' ) ); ?></div>
        </div><!-- #nav-below -->

        <?php else : ?>
        <h2 class="center"><?php _e('Not Found', 'kubrick'); ?></h2>
        <p class="center"><?php _e('Sorry, but you are looking for something that isn&#8217;t here.', 'kubrick'); ?></p>
        <?php get_search_form(); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div><br>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Please don't use `query_posts`.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755/21376) Just don't. Create a new query with `WP_Query`.

Secondly, I am not sure how you are trying to use multiple authors in the query but I assume you are using `author` and a comma separated string of IDs or `author__in` and an array. For example:

```
$query = new WP_Query( 'author=2,6,17,38' );

// or
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'author__in' => array( 2, 6 ) ) );
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Author_Parameters

Either should work.

Also:
`showposts` has been deprecated for a long time now. You should be using `posts_per_page`. I also suspect that you should be using a filter on `pre_get_posts` rather than creating a new query at all.

Comment: Thanks for responding so fast.Well I'm not able to explain it (sorry my bad english)this link below this one with the same problem as mine, unfortunately no one came to help. Perhaps you can understand better than me explaining.

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/coauthors-plugin-issue-wp_query-for-author-produces-no-results

Thank you!